# Mismatch between bytes sent over QDataStream from client to the server

Tags: c++, qt, qtcpsocket

I am trying to send a `QByteArray` on `QTcpSocket` . The problem that I face is that although I send an array of length 25, at the server it receives 59 bytes . Here is my sample code :

```
//client
QDataStream out(qctcpSocket);
out<<qByteArray;  // qByteArray is of length 25
const int nbBytes = qctcpSocket->write(qByteArray); // nbBytes returbs 25 

//server
TArray<char> data;
uint32 pendingData = 0;
TArray<char> newData; // customized Template for Array
    newData.InsertZeroed(0, pendingData);
    int32 bytesRead = 0;
    rcvSocket->Recv(reinterpret_cast<uint8*>(newData.GetData()), pendingData, bytesRead);
    data += newData;//length is 59 !!
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]: what's `InsertZeroed`? What's `rcvSocket` and `Recv`? Etc.

Comment: @Angew InsertZeroed is just like memset and rcvSocket is the servers receving socket pointer

Comment: Well, then some of them is probably wrong. Perhaps you're appending somewhere where you expect to overwrite, etc. Without a [mcve], we cannot help.

Answer (score 1):

I see two issues in your client code. Since you're using a (supposedly) connected socket as the data stream underlying device:

```
QDataStream out(qctcpSocket);
```

you're sending data through the socket, with this line:

```
out<<qByteArray;  // qByteArray is of length 25
```

then you're sending more data with the next one:

```
const int nbBytes = qctcpSocket->write(qByteArray); // nbBytes returbs 25
```

This is the first issue: you're trying to send the same data twice. But data differs between each call (and this is the second issue): performing the first send, using the stream, will put on the socket an array of bytes long `QByteArray::size + 4`, the four extra bytes being added by the stream object (it's a big-endian 32 bit integer preceding the actual byte array and holding its length in bytes).

The second send, instead, puts on the socket only the 25 bytes in the byte array, which, I guess, it's what you wanted in the first place.

My advice is to get rid of the data stream altogether and use the `write` method of the `QTcpSocket` class, and this should be the best option if you're not using Qt on the other endpoint (the server).

If you still wanted to use the stream, get rid of the `write` on the sender side, and be sure to use a `QDataStream` object on the receiving endpoint, so you have to:

```
//Build a QByteArray out of the incoming bytes:
QByteArray raw_data = ...

//Use it as the stream device
QDataStream stream(raw_data);

//Use another byte array to fetch the data out of the stream
QByteArray data;
stream >> data;
```

Or you can manually strip the leading four bytes, which I don't recommend, really.

Comment: The advice to drop the data stream is not necessary. The data stream is well documented and it's perfectly compatible with non-Qt projects.

Answer (score 1):

The server seems to run on Unreal engine. This is important!

You're sending your data twice: once via the data stream, next time via `write`. Don't do that: send it once, using your preferred method.

If you want to use the data stream:

```
void Client::send(const QByteArray &data) {
  QDataStream out(this->qctcpSocket);
  out << data;
}
```

There are 4 + `data.size()` bytes written to the stream. The initial 4 bytes carry the little-endian length of the array that follows. If you don't want to send the array length, you must use `writeRawData` on the stream *or* `write` on the socket:

```
void Client::send(const QByteArray &data) {
  // use when there's a data stream already on the socket
  this->out.writeRawData(data.constData(), data.size());
  // or
  // use when there's no data stream available
  this->qctcpSocket->write(data);
}
```

In the server, you're having two major issues:

1. You're assuming that the data arrives all in one chunk. There is no such guarantee: for all you know, your receive data handler can be notified of a single byte being available.
2. You're only processing one packet - you might receive any number of them, and you must keep reading them until no more data is available.

Let's have:

```
include <utility> // Unreal headers are omitted in this example

class Server {
  FSocket *rcvSocket;
  ...
};

bool Server::hardReceiveError() {
  // the socket has lost synchronization - we can't proceed!
  rcvSocket->Close();
  ...
  return false;
}

void Server::processPacket(const TArray<uint8> &pkt) {
  // process the packet
  ...
}

// Apparently the Unreal engine doesn't care enough to offer this (?)
template <typename T> 
std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, T>::type fromLittleEndian(const void *buf) {
  T ret;
  memcpy(&ret, buf, sizeof(ret));
  if (!FGenericPlatformProperties::IsLittleEndian()) {
    uint8 *r = reinterpret_cast<uint8*>(&ret);
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(T)/2; ++i)
      std::swap(r[i], r[sizeof(T)-1-i]);
  }
  return ret;
}
```

To receive the byte array data sent via the data stream, you have to handle the size:

```
// handle all available data
void Server::receiveHandlerDataStream() {
  while (receiveDataStream());
}

// receive one packet
bool Server::receiveDataStream() {
  uint32 pendingData = 0;
  rcvSocket->HasPendingData(pendingData);
  if (pendingData < 4)
    return false;
  int32 bytesRead = 0;
  uint8 buf[4];
  rcvSocket->Recv(buf, sizeof(buf), bytesRead, ESocketReceiveFlags::Peek);
  if (bytesRead != 4)
    return hardReceiveError();
  auto length = fromLittleEndian<int32>(buf);
  if (pendingData < (4+length)
    return false;
  bytesRead = 0;
  rcvSocket->Recv(buf, sizeof(buf), bytesRead, ESocketReceiveFlags::None);
  if (bytesRead != 4)
    return hardReceiveError();
  TArray<uint8> data;
  data.AddUninitialized(length);
  bytesRead = 0;
  if (length) { // we may have 0-length packets
    rcvSocket->Recv(data.GetData(), data.ArrayNum, bytesRead, ESocketReceiveFlags::None);
    if (bytesRead != length)
      return hardReceiveError();
  }
  processPacket(data);
  return true;
}
```

To receive the raw packets instead - not sent as a bytearray via the data stream:

```
// handle all available data
void Server::receiveHandlerRaw() {
  while (receiveRaw());
}

// receive one packet
bool Server::receiveRaw() {
  uint32 pendingData = 0;
  constexpr uint32 expects = 25;
  rcvSocket->HasPendingData(pendingData);
  if (pendingData < expects)
    return false;
  int32 bytesRead = 0;
  TArray<uint8> data;
  data.AddUninitialized(expects);
  rcvSocket->Recv(data.GetData(), data.ArrayNum, bytesRead, ESocketReceiveFlags::None);
  if (bytesRead != data.ArrayNum)
    return hardReceiveError();
  processPacket(data);
  return true;
}
```

Note: This is untested.

Comment: Hey Kuba, do you have an idea why the OP gets 59 bytes and not 54?

Comment: It usually reduces to this: https://media.giphy.com/media/ghBmDOgWxuQCs/giphy.gif I consider not including a repro case that **asserts OPs bold claims as to sizes and whatnot** to be lying :) People don't understand that code speaks for itself. You don't need to know academic English to write `Q_ASSERT(buf.size() == 25)`.